# Inference time for text genration using fine-tuned gpt2

Tags: python, natural-language, language-models

I have re-trained GPT2 model using over 10 million sentences for QA. And while testing also I am getting very good results. The only problem now I am facing is that I have millions of test data that I need to process at once.
Referring to open-ai [github](https://github.com/openai/gpt-2/blob/master/src/interactive_conditional_samples.py), I have made few changes by looping over test sentences to get the prediction rather that getting output for one sentence at one time. Using CPU I am getting ~30sec for predicting output of each sentence. But we all know from a product perspective if we have millions of data, then this speed is not feasible.
So how can I reduce inference timing of my model?

Comment: GPT-2 is an absolutely massive  model, and you're using a CPU. In fact, even using a Tesla T4 there are [reports on Github](https://github.com/openai/gpt-2/issues/233) that this is taking ms-scale time on batches of 10-100 docs (~60 tokens), which is well beneath your use case. There are, of course, a bunch of hardware considerations that could affect inference time -- but GPT-2 is massive, and I think this is a limitation of this model. You could try looking at a smaller language model (or some other architecture depending on your task) and trying to use that.

Comment: You can use Nvidia TensorRT library for faster inference: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/optimizing-t5-and-gpt-2-for-real-time-inference-with-tensorrt/